# How to create S3 bucket to avoid name collisions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a program that creates S3 buckets programmatically but I run into an issue where bucket fails if name is already created because it is a global namespace.

How can I programmatically ensure/create names that are globally unique in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works to use my *Account ID* and *region* as a part of the bucket name, for example: `my-bucket-1234567890-us-east-1`.

This is nicer and provides relevant and deterministic info than to use a random string. Of course your can add some random as well:

```java
int i = 0;
String bucketName;
do {
    bucketName = myName + "-" accountId + "-" region + "-" + (++i);
} while (bucketExists(bucketName));
```

You can use [`GetIdentityCaller()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) to get the account's info.
Just be aware, the limit for a bucket name is 63 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep trying to create a bucket until it works:

```
while True:
    generate a UUID
    try to create the bucket called 'foo-UUID'
    if it worked:
        break
```

For example, the UUID could be a 4-character portion of a `UUID.randomUUID()`. Use a useful prefix that relates to your company and use-case.